# Copy constructor for derived class, without testing all the types?

Tags: c++

i have a class that holds an std::vector with many elements of the same base class but different type. Now i want to implement a copy constructor for it.

There are really many different kind of objects so is there a better way than getting all the types and have a huge if-branch to copy all of them?

```
MyObject::MyObject(const MyObject &rhs)
{
    // copy all the parameters
    for(size_t i=0; i<rhs.m_parameters.size(); i++)
    {
        Parameter* p = rhs.m_parameters[i];
        if(dynamic_cast<ParameterType1*>(p) != NULL)
        {
            ParameterType1* p_old = dynamic_cast<ParameterType1*>(p);
            ParameterType1* p_new = new ParameterType1(*p_old);
            m_parameters.push_back(p_new);
        }
        else if(dynamic_cast<ParameterType2*>(p) != NULL)
        {
            ParameterType2* p_old = dynamic_cast<ParameterType2*>(p);
            ParameterType2* p_new = new ParameterType2(*p_old, this);
            m_parameters.push_back(p_new);
        }
        else if(dynamic_cast<ParameterType3*>(p) != NULL)
        {
            ParameterType3* p_old = dynamic_cast<ParameterType3*>(p);
            ParameterType3* p_new = new ParameterType3(*p_old, this);
            m_parameters.push_back(p_new);
        }    
        else if
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: create virtual method `Parameter* makeCopy()` for each of child class and use it `m_parameters.push_back(p->makeCopy())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create virtual method `Parameter* makeCopy()` in base class and implement it for each of child class and use `m_parameters.push_back(p->makeCopy())`